# Fade in/out list of DOM elements one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I've got a web page with a large list of hidden li elements that I'd like to endlessly loop over and display on a small visible list of 5 li elements.  I'm currently using a recursive method that calls itself with the next li element after each update which works fine to fade in/out each visible li one at a time forever.  However once I try to change the html in the visible li to the html in the hidden li that I'm looping over all hell breaks loose.  All 5 visible li's get set to the first 5 hidden li's and fade in/out all at once.  Then there is a long pause, the page freezes for a bit and eventually all 5 visible li's will fade in/out again and still be set to the first 5 hidden li's.  It's like once I try to change the html all of a sudden the entire looping happens all at once and I can't perceive why that would be the case.

```
$(function () {
    fade($("#all-donors").first(), 1);           
});

function fade(elem, curItem) {
    var curElement = $("#donor" + curItem);
    //curElement.html(elem.html());  //This line breaks it
    curElement.fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        curItem++;
        if (curItem > 5) {
            curItem = 1;
        }

        // If we're not on the last <li>
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            // Call fade on the next <li>
            fade(elem.next(), curItem);
        }
        else {
            // Else go back to the start
            fade(elem.siblings(':first'), curItem);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: fadeIn() is asynchronous. That's why you have the feeling they all move together. You'd better use the callback of fadeIn() to go to next item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Loop `LI's` from just 1 `<UL>` element, and to loop `<LI>` tags from 2 `<UL>` elements, using the first UL as a visible UL and the 2nd UL as the `looper UL`

## 1ST APPROACH

[JSFIDDLE FINAL RESULT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wNF36/1/)

Fade in, only after fading out is complete.  And use `class` to hide all li elements except the first li initially and no need to send the `curItem` parameter to the function, which could only mess things up, just send the `.next` or `:first` element to the function instead.  And no need to use `.length > 0`, `.length` is good enough.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunc($(".show"));
});

function myFunc(oEle)
{
    oEle.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        if (oEle.next().length)
        {
            oEle.next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
                myFunc(oEle.next());
            });
        }
        else
        {
            oEle.siblings(":first").fadeIn('slow', function(){
                myFunc(oEle.siblings(":first"));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="listitem">
    <li class="show">Test 1</li>
    <li class="hidden">Test 2</li>
    <li class="hidden">Test 3</li>
    <li class="hidden">Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

## 2ND APPROACH, and answer to your question!

[JSFIDDLE FINAL RESULT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wNF36/3/)

jQUERY:

```
var curIndex = 0, 
    nextIndex = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunc($(".show").children().eq(curIndex), $(".hidden").children().eq(nextIndex));
});

function myFunc(curLI, nextLI)
{
    curLI.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).html(nextLI.html()).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            curIndex = curLI.next().length ? ++curIndex : 0;
            nextIndex = nextLI.next().length ? ++nextIndex : 0;
            myFunc($(".show").children("li").eq(curIndex), $(".hidden").children("li").eq(nextIndex));
        });
    });
}
```

HTML STRUCTURE:

```
<ul class="listitem show">
    <li>Blah 1</li>
    <li>Blah 2</li>
    <li>Blah 3</li>
    <li>Blah 4</li>
    <li>Blah 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="listitem hidden">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
    <li>Test 7</li>
    <li>Test 8</li>
    <li>Test 9</li>
    <li>Test 10</li>
    <li>Test 11</li>
    <li>Test 12</li>
    <li>Test 13</li>
    <li>Test 14</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.listitem {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.hidden li {
    display: none;
}
```

Sorry, guess I didn't fully understand what you were asking for exactly.  Well, hopefully this helps someone, if not you.

Comment: This isn't really what I'm doing.  The 5 li elements that I'm using to display my large list of hidden li elements should all always be visible, I'm just looping through them to display the next text from the hidden in the next text from the visible; so looping through 2 lists at once.  Given your code I tried adding a callback to fadeOut() and changing the html of the next visible li to the html of the next hidden li in there before calling fadeIn() but still ran into the same issue :(

Comment: @Fenoec - Updated my answer for you, with better code, IMO!  And doesn't use a TIMER.  Use the 2nd APPROACH, which I believe is what you are after:  jsfiddle on this here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wNF36/2/

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.  I changed this to my accepted answer as it also seems to fix an asynchronous issue of skipping elements sometimes I was having with the other answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I think this is what you're looking for.
It can be changed for your needs, but it's the basic thing working.

JSFiddle **(updated)**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ut86V/4/

HTML:

```
<ul class="list1">

  <li>blahxx</li>
  <li>blahxxx</li>
  <li>blahxxxx</li>
  <li>blahxxxxx</li>
  <li>blahxxxxxx</li>
</ul>


<ul class="list2">
  <li>blah1</li>
  <li>blah2</li>
  <li>blah3</li>
  <li>blah4</li>
  <li>blah5</li>
  <li>blah6</li>
  <li>blah7</li>
  <li>blah8</li>
  <li>blah9</li>
  <li>blah0</li>
  <li>blah11</li>
  <li>blah12</li>
  <li>blah13</li>
  <li>blah14</li>
  <li>blah15</li>
  <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function popList( speed ) {

    speed = speed || 2000;
    var $list1 = $('.list1 li');
    var $list2 = $('.list2 li');
    var item = 0;
    var source = 0;

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ ) {

        $list1.eq( i ).html( $list2.eq( i ).html() );
        source = i+1;

    }

    var replaceContent = function() {           

        $list1
            .eq( item )
            .delay( speed/2 )
            .animate(
                { opacity: 0 }, 
                speed/4, 
                function() {

                    var content = $list2.eq( source ).html();

                    $(this)
                        .html( content )
                        .animate(
                            { opacity: 1 }, 
                            speed/4 
                        );

                    item = ( item >= 4 ) ? 0 : item+1;
                    source = ( source >= $list2.length-1 ) ? 0 : source+1;

                    replaceContent();

                }
            );           

    };

    replaceContent();


};

$(function() {
    popList(5000);
});
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for and got it working now!  I'd vote you up but don't have enough rep :(

Comment: This solution actually ran into an asynchronous issue and was skipping an element every once in a while so I'm accepting the other answer.  Still upvoted this as it was helpful and could be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Fenoec.
In the interest of helping others, and hopefully you, I've amended it slightly. I still feel the code I've written is quite neat and succinct, but I changed it to be a infinitely self-invoking function instead. Take a look at my edited answer above, please. Simey.